# RabbitMQ Server TLS, client alert: Fatal - Certificate Unknown when starting service

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

Have RabbitMQ configured to enable TLS with certificates. Key, Cert, and CA defined in .conf file. Upon service startup, error is thrown. Cannot find the cause for this to be thrown and logging isn't giving any more information at the debug level.

Get a client alert failure and am not certain of cause.

2019-03-22 10:04:18.690 [info] <0.7.0> Server startup complete; 4 plugins started.
* rabbitmq_amqp1_0
* rabbitmq_management
* rabbitmq_management_agent
* rabbitmq_web_dispatch

2019-03-22 10:04:24.831 [debug] <0.689.0> Supervisor {<0.689.0>,rabbit_connection_sup} started rabbit_connection_helper_sup:start_link() at pid <0.690.0>

2019-03-22 10:04:24.831 [debug] <0.689.0> Supervisor {<0.689.0>,rabbit_connection_sup} started rabbit_reader:start_link(<0.690.0>, {acceptor,{0,0,0,0},5671}) at pid <0.691.0>

2019-03-22 10:04:24.909 [info] <0.688.0> TLS server: In state certify received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Certificate Unknown

Comment: I'm assuming an application is making a connection to this server. Is that correct? Have you gone through the troubleshooting guide? https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

Our certs didn't have the correct type of X509v3 Extended Key Usage on the cert.
For x509 Auth, you'll need to assign client web auth when creating the certificate.

> X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
>                   TLS Web Client Authentication

This won't fix the issue if your certificate CA is broken and can't be verified, but for my issue, this was the resolution.